# Wix installer progress bar

Tags: wix, progress-bar, wix3.8

I have created a basic progress bar in my wix project.
I want to change the fill in color of that progress bar when installation proceeds.
I have searched for the solution at many places but was unable to find one.
so if someone has a solution to it, please reply.

Comment: Hi and welcome on the StackOverflow! 
So... what exactly have you tried? Can you post any code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the msi as your UI, you cannot change the progress color. The only UI change that can be modified is the text format and the position of other controls.

If you need to do a custom color or other UI changes, you can write a managed WIX WPF installer.